# How do I fix this chair?

Tags: chair

This is my dining table chair. It’s back support rod broke. I tried fixing it with wooden glue but it keeps breaking. Any advise how can I fix it without nails as that can hurt someone’s back. Or is there a place I can find wooden rod like this and fix it?

[image: chair]

Comment: Your question might be better suited to the Woodworking Stack Exchange, though even there you might not get the answer you want, as this repair job is likely to include a combination of many techniques to execute properly.  I don't think many people will want to recommend a "quick and dirty" repair.  The answer by Solar Mike is what you can reasonably expect as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would be separating the top rail, then removing that cross.

Once the cross is out then it can have a new bit made as trying to join that broken bit will not be very successful.

Make the new tenons that go into the top rail and glue as reassembling.